# Understanding flutter syntax

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm reviewing someones flutter code, and there is some code in there i don't understand what its doing.

I don't understand some of the syntax since in never seen it in any other language.

Here are three examples...

```
1.  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()
    ..forceAndroidLocationManager = true;

2.  final firstName = appState?.user?.firstName ?? '';

3.  var envelope = new Envelope()
    ..from = 'support@example.com'
    ..recipients.add(Globals.sosEmail)
    ..ccRecipients.add(email)
    ..subject = '$firstName $lastName hello. ${new DateTime.now()}'
    ..text = "Hello"'
    ..html ='<p>Hey!</p>';
```

What is (2) doing? What does `?.` and `?? ''` mean?

There is syntax where there is two dots in a row like in (1) `..forceAndroidLocationManager`, or `..from`, `..text` etc.

Anybody knows what the above 3 examples of code does? 
Thanks!

Comment: read https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour carefully

Comment: take a look at [operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-)
This means that you can make several operations on the same object. Example from the dart website:

```
querySelector('#confirm') // Get an object.
..text = 'Confirm' // Use its members.
..classes.add('important')
..onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```

The second example is about [null-aware operators](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb)

```
final firstName = appState?.user?.firstName ?? '';
```

What's happening here is that we have a variable called `appState` and `appState?.user` means that we're only supposed to try to access `user` if appState is not null (so we don't get a nullpointer error. Same goes for `user?.firstname`.

Finally, `??` means 'set 'firstName' to appState.user.firstName if it's not null, otherwise set it to ''.

The third example is the same thing as the first.